# Have two JDK installed, how to switch the java compiler in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering how to switch the java compiler in Eclipse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Window > Prefrences > Java > Installed JREs

Comment: This does change the JRE, however it doesn't change the compiler.  I require my other IDE to use JDK 1.7 and Eclipse to use JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 17):

Eclipse does not use the compiler in the JDK, just the runtime libraries.  The compiler is embedded in Eclipse (so you can run on a plain JRE).

You set all the compiler properties in the Java->Compiler preference window, and the class libraries in the chosen JRE.

Comment: That's interesting. So even if i get the latest JDK on my system, Eclipse still uses the old compiler that came with Eclipse? See my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710030/is-jdk-required-for-android-developement

Comment: Yes.  This is why Java 8 support in Eclipse 4.4 is backported to 4.3

Comment: ok. That makes me wonder if Eclipse also has an embedded JDK? Or only just the compiler? I could not figure out anything looking at the Eclipse installation folder.

Comment: Eclipse has an embedded compiler and not any more.  The downloads from eclipse.org does not contain a Java distribution, but for instance IBM brands Eclipse with their own brand and include their own Java which is then tested as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse website says that changing the VM in Eclipse.ini is the most certain way to change the underlying VM. Here is a snippet from the eclipse site.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

> "One of the most recommended options to use is to specify a specific
>   JVM for Eclipse to run on. Doing this ensures that you are absolutely
>   certain which JVM Eclipse will run in and insulates you from system
>   changes that can alter the "default" JVM for your system. Many a user
>   has been tripped up because they thought they knew what JVM would be
>   used by default, but they thought wrong. eclipse.ini lets you be
>   CERTAIN."

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses their own compiler named 'Eclipse Compiler for Java(ECJ)' embedded with **JDT** for compiling java code. We can only switch java run time environment.

Answer (score 1):

go to Window->Preferences->Java->Compile.You can change java compiler in this menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the menu You select Window -> Preferences, then in tree you search for Java and Complier

There you have Complier complacence level and you can choose.

Comment: Are you sure that changing the compiler compliance level actually changes the compiler being used by Eclipse? The warning message in Eclipse says to install the required JRE(does not have a compiler), not JDK(has the compiler), when changing the compliance level.