# Is JDK required for android developement

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse on Ubuntu for a long time now to successfully run and build android apk's. But i have just realized i had never installed a JDK on my system, only the JRE. So my question is isn't JDK required for Android development?

Below are some pints to prove that there is no reference to a JDK anywhere on my system :

1. The $JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the JRE folder `/home/faizal/DEV/jre1.7.0_55`.
2. `readlink -f $(which java)` also points to the same JRE folder.
3. Even Eclipse points to the same location if i look at :

   Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
4. `Eclipse -> Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details -> Configuration` also points to same location :

   java.home=/home/faizal/DEV/jre1.7.0_55

Comment: Perhaps eclipse has some type of built-in jdk supplied?

Comment: @Rogue that is not true. If i remove the JRE folder, Eclipse fails to launch with the error : `A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/faizal/DEV/eclipse-luna/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH`

Answer (score 8):

According to System Requirements --> Development Tools in the below link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

> JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)

Note: The Eclipse ADT plug-in requires Java 7 if your compilation target is the L developer preview.

Comment: That's just plain wierd! How am i working without the JDK then?

Comment: @faizal your environment variable should link to jdk not jre. You must be having jdk installed

Comment: @faizal Have you been doing Android development or just plain ol' Java?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have been doing only Android development

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right. But for some unknown reason, I had pointed $JAVA_HOME to the JRE from the start and it has worked till now.

Comment: @faizal goto windows preferences java compiler. what you see there?

Comment: @faizal you still use eclipse right? I am taking about eclipse --> Windows in the toolbar

Comment: oops :) i see compiler compliance as 1.7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57193/discussion-between-faizal-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk has embedded jdk .

Comment: you mean it is inside `android.jar` ?

Comment: Yes, you can check it in android.jar.